# Shell script to stop an application at power down in linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, kill, intel-edison

I wrote a posture sensing code in edison device in c. I have succeeded in invoking the application at power up. But I need a shell script to close this application at power down.

I have tried `kill {pid}` command line operation. Even though I killed the command, during power down device need an extra 5 min to stop that application. Am I missing something here..

Comment: did you try `kill -9 {pid}` ??

Comment: its worked. thanks @Maraboc

Comment: But in general, `kill -9` is wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application should *explicitly* handle some [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s, in particular `SIGTERM` which is sent (by some system program doing a [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)) at shutdown.

Sending a `SIGKILL` (e.g. `kill -9` or `kill -KILL`) is unsafe (in particular to server maintaining some state on disk, e.g. database servers, but also any software having some kind of persistent state, or configuration, or logs...) because the killed program has no opportunity to clean its mess, flush its buffers, and save a consistent state on the disk.

So the robust policy is to `kill -TERM`, then a few seconds later `kill -QUIT` and a few seconds later `kill -KILL`. Hence, robust applications should handle `SIGTERM` and `SIGQUIT` (but `SIGKILL` cannot be caught)...
You might handle `SIGPWR` (but not every system has it or manage it properly; some [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) hardware & software do).

Perhaps your system uses [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) and you could take advantage of that (e.g. [D-bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) things).